# How to minimize whole application in android?

Tags: android, tabbar

I was developed android application. More over i have completed, but i want to minimize option. I have used tab bar. In that i want to minimize tab. When user click minimize tab to minimize whole application.
my tabbar code as..

```
    public class tabbar extends TabActivity implements OnTabChangeListener {
    private Context mContext;
    TabHost tabHost;
    int tabload=0;
    private AlertDialog alertDialog;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tabbar);
        //mContext=this;

        /** TabHost will have Tabs */
        tabHost = (TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(this);



        /** TabSpec used to create a new tab.
         * By using TabSpec only we can able to setContent to the tab.
         * By using TabSpec setIndicator() we can set name to tab. */

        /** tid1 is firstTabSpec Id. Its used to access outside. */
        TabSpec firstTabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab_id1");
        TabSpec secondTabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab_id2");
        TabSpec thirdTabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab_id3");


        /** TabSpec setIndicator() is used to set name for the tab. */
        /** TabSpec setContent() is used to set content for a particular tab. */
        firstTabSpec.setIndicator("FRIENDS").setContent(new Intent(this,view_friends.class));
        secondTabSpec.setIndicator("GROUPS").setContent(new Intent(this,groups.class));
        thirdTabSpec.setIndicator("SIGN OUT").setContent(new Intent(this,signout.class));


        /** Add tabSpec to the TabHost to display. */
        tabHost.addTab(firstTabSpec);
        tabHost.addTab(secondTabSpec);
        tabHost.addTab(thirdTabSpec);



    }



        @Override
        public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

         for(int i=0;i<tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount();i++)
            {
                     tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#343333")); //unselected
            }
                      tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(tabHost.getCurrentTab()).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#f1a026"));     // selected
    //         if(tabId.equals("tab_id1")){
    //             LocalActivityManager manager = getLocalActivityManager();
    //             manager.destroyActivity("tab_id1", true);
    //             manager.startActivity("tab_id1", new Intent(this, view_friends.class));
    //         }

    }
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        tabHost.setCurrentTab(2);
        System.gc();
    }


}
```

In this code if any correction need please help...

give me a sample code..

Comment: Define "minimize". Are you looking for [`Activity.finish()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish())?

Comment: You want what now? You want the same behaviour as the "home" button? It's not really clear.

Comment: yes i want home button behaviour in my tab click

Answer (score 50, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by minimize. If you want to hide your app and present the user with the homescreen you can use the following intent.

```
Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(startMain);
```

Although the Home button is more than sufficient if a user wants to hide your app

Comment: How to minimize from other application?

Answer (score 0):

Try calling this `moveTaskToBack(true);` boolean.

Comment: This will cause unintended side effects, it just put the activity to backstack, not the whole application....

Comment: OK, but this is very usefull for apps with one activity whos have `launchMode="singleTop"`. Thank YOU for vote.

Comment: But the question is asked about minimizing the whole application!