# Minimize programmatically and restore my activity when I click notification

Tags: android, notifications, minimize

It is possible to minimize programmatically my activity and restore this activity when I click notification ?

Comment: This might help! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7530407/how-to-minimize-whole-application-in-android

Comment: and this! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13581574/android-open-or-restart-app-after-clicking-push-notification-using-flag-activi