# "Minimize" an Activity in Android (don't finish it)

Tags: android, android-activity

I want to "minimize" the application, leaving it in background doing exactly the same that when the home button is pressed when the user clicks a button (but don't finish it) How can I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4647231/android-minimize-application

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sending Activity to background with out finishing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2041891/sending-activity-to-background-with-out-finishing)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use the [`moveTaskToBack(boolean)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#moveTaskToBack%28boolean%29) method of Activity.

Answer (score -2):

### Short answer:

you can't.

### Explanation:

The android `Activity` Life-cycle does not give you that level of control. If the Android OS needs the memory, or the phone interrupts your activity, it may be killed.

Then again, it may not. Android will pause you activity, and application, and if possible it will not destroy any `Activity`s.

### The Fix:

You need to listen for the `onPause()` and `onResume()` events in your `Activity`. And you have to serialize and deserialize your data in each case, saving the state of the `Activity` when it is paused and resumed.

There's some good explanation of how this works on the Android developer site, [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle).

And if you simply want a `Button` in your app to act as the home button, you create an `Intent` for that with `ACTION_MAIN` and category `CATEGORY_HOME`.

```
Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(startMain);
```